# How to put many loaded numbered dataframes into a list?

Tags: r

how can I efficiently call a larger range of numbered dataframes, i.e. `T1,T2,T3,...`, without explicitly having to write them down? I tried the code below, but that doesn't work..

```
lrange <- 1:10
tseries <- as.list(paste0("T", lrange,sep = ""))
```

I obtain something that can't be used e.g. by `do.call("rbind",tseries)`

Comment: `L <- mget(paste0("T", 1:10))` Even better it would be, if you construct the list from the process who is generating the objects `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, ...

Comment: so its a named object and `as.list` doesn't take that.. thanks! I first wanted to get the code running and then improve on it.